# What is the proper syntax for action in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a function set like this:

```
  func alertControllerBackgroundTapped(myString: String) {
       ///do something in here
        })
    }
```

which I am trying to invoke here:

```
 alert.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(CICViewController.alertControllerBackgroundTapped(_:))))
```

But obviously this will gives me an error since I am not setting my arguments (myString) correctly.

What is the proper syntax in this?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding this action to `UITapGestureRecognizer`, the action must have a proper signature - a single-argument function taking `UITapGestureRecognizer` and not returning anything. Inside the recognizer body you are free to make a call to your function that takes a string:

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    alertControllerBackgroundTapped("Hello!") 
}
```

Add `handleTap` as the action instead of `alertControllerBackgroundTapped`:

```
alert.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(
    UITapGestureRecognizer(
        target: self
    ,   action:#selector(CICViewController.handleTap(_:))
    )
)
```

Comment: I'd like to pass the argument from inside the alert block rather than in a handleTap func....

Comment: @GeorgeAsda Gesture recognizer is the one calling your function, so you can't make it work like that out of the box. [Here is a solution that attempts to work around that limitation](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/3815) (at the bottom of the article).

Comment: @GeorgeAsda find a way to keep track of the text that was selected under the tap. If its a `UIAlertController`, use the `UIAlertAction`'s handler. Otherwise use the `locationInView(_:) ` function in the `UITapGestureRecognizer `